# Convert String to Date format with timezone throwing parsing error

Tags: java, date, timezone

I have String s1 as below.

String s1 = "2021-10-12T14:28:46.615+00:00"

I want to convert it to exact same java.util.Date instance - 2021-10-12T14:28:46.615+00:00

Using below is returning "2021-10-12T14:38:15.000-0400"

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sss");
Date d1 = dateFormat.parse(s1);
```

And using below is throwing parsing error

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ");
```

Date d1 = dateFormat.parse(s1);

Pls advice the dateformat I should be using

Comment: Your first `SimpleDateFormat` ignores the offset and the second one tries to parse a zone, not an offset. Do you have to use an outdated API? You could simply do `OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(s1);`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. With your change, I am getting "2021-10-12T14:28:46.615" but it is OffsetDateTime while my target required datatype is java.util.Date.

Comment: Look into DateTimeFormatter and ZonedDateTime.  SimpleDateFormat and Date are outdated.

Comment: If you have to create a `java.util.Date`, then use `Date date = Date.from(odt.toInstant());` using the `OffsetDateTime` from my first comment.

Comment: As others said, you should avoid the terrible `Date`/`Calendar` classes whenever possible. Use only the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. To convert to and fro, see new `to…`/`from…` conversion methods added to the old legacy classes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way if you must use the legacy (and deprecated) Date class. But you should focus on using the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package.

```
String s1 = "2021-10-12T14:28:46.615+00:00";


OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(s1);
long epochMilli = odt.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
Date date = new Date(epochMilli);
System.out.println(date);
```

prints

```
Tue Oct 12 10:28:46 EDT 2021
```

Note that since the offset is `+00:00` the timezone is for `UTC/Greenwich` and adjusted accordingly.  If required, you can use `.plusHours()` or `.minusHours()` on the value returned by `parse` to adjust the offset based on locality.

Comment: Good Answer. More briefly: `java.util.Date.from( OffsetDateTime.parse( "2021-10-12T14:28:46.615+00:00" ).toInstant() )`.